# Find the area between the graphs of $f(x) = 3 - |x+1|$ and $g(x) = x^{2} + 2x - 8$.

Tags: calculus

I was given the functions $f(x) = 3 - |x+1|$ and $g(x) = x^2 + 2x - 8$ and was told to find the area between the two curves when one was an absolute value function.

The hint was given to go back to the definition of absolute value as a piece wise defined function but I don't know what that is. I'm completely lost and don't know where to start or what to do that this point.

Comment: To @Jared: Are you able to draw both curves?

Comment: The absolute value function $y=|x|$ is defined piecewise as $$y=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}-x& \textrm{if}\ x<0\\ x& \textrm{if}\ x\geq 0.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Have you graphed the 2 functions? This should help you.

Comment: I have both of the function graphed.

Comment: So, you know which function is upper bound of that area, as well as which function is lower bound. Next, you have to find their intersection points, and to find the area you can use definite integral... By answer is 45 :)

Comment: \begin{align*}
\int_{-4}^{2} ((3-|x+1|) - (x^{2}+2x-8))\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}

Comment: I found the notes for this problem but it hasn't helped me at all. This is my definite integral before I simplified it and ran the simple power rule on it and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and for some reason, I get 13 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let us solve first the equation $f(x) = g(x)$:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = g(x) & \Longleftrightarrow 3 - |x+1| = x^{2} + 2x - 8 = (x+1)^{2} - 9 = |x+1|^{2} - 9\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x+1|^{2} + |x+1| - 12 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x+1| = 3
\end{align*}

Whence we conclude that $x\in\{-4,2\}$.

Once $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for $x\in[-4,2]$, the integral to be solved is given by
\begin{align*}
\int_{-4}^{2} (f(x) - g(x))\mathrm{d}x = \ldots
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I certainly will try my best.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is saying that we can think of the function $|x|$ as:

$$|x|:=\begin{cases} x &\text{if } x\geq{0}\\
-x & x<0\end{cases}$$

This is a piecewise function since $|x|=x$ for the "piece" $x\geq{0}$ and $|x|=-x$ for the "piece" $x<0$.

What you now want to do is try to express $f(x)$ in a similar way (break it up into two pieces), and then find the area between each of these pieces and $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value function is not differentiable at $f(0)=0$ as it is not smooth. Because of this we cannot cleanly integrate over the function. Instead we split it into a piecewise defined function such that our new equation is continuous over the ineterval. To think of a function as a piecewise function break it apart into its components. For the case of absolute value you can define it as follows:  f(x)=|x|=[ \begin{cases} 
      -x & x< 0 \\
       x & x\geq 0\\
   \end{cases}
]

You will also need the intersection points of these two equations. You can find this by setting them equal and solving for x. Once you have this information you can split the integrals such that if $x<0 \, f(x)=-x$ and so on for the second integral. At the end you can simply add both areas together.

Comment: I was having trouble figuring out breaking the equation into a piece wise function. Every example I've seen only is like f(x)=|x+4| but I haven't been able to find an example like my equation of f(x)=3-|x+1| Do I have to solve this first and then break it up?

Comment: Try to think of the values inside and outside the bars as shifts to the original function. If it is on the outside of the |x| it will be a shift up (if positive, down if negative). On the inside of the bars eg |x+1| a positive value is a shift left and a negative value is a shift right. Abs is not differentiable when the interior value is equal to zero or when x= -1.